# Calling function to clear localstorage value from unit test - angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-unit-test

I want to test the if the `localStorage` is cleared down whenever I call my function.

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Logout on reaching login screen so we can login
    this.authService.logout();
  }
```

**authService**

```
logout() {
    // remove logged in user from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }
```

**TEST**

```
fit('ngOnInit should logout user stored in localStorage', () => {
    // Exmample data stored as token
    localStorage.setItem('token', 'someUserToken');

    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(localStorage.getItem('token')).toEqual('{}');
});
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: You remove `currentUser` but you expect `token` to equal `{}` ... Are you okay ?

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks for pointing out my mistake. All works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit testing should only concern the feature you're testing.

This means that you should not check if the local storage is cleared : that's not what your component does. Your component calls your auth service, which then clears the storage.

This means you should test if the correct method is called.

```
it('ngOnInit should call auth.logout', () => {
    spyOn(component['authService'], 'logout');

    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(component['authService'].logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Could I not incorporate both things into the one test?
ie have `localStorage.setItem('token','blah');` and then expect it to be cleared below? in practise, I have tried this, and it does not clear the localStorage...

Comment: You can, but it's not best practice (and probably not even unit testing)

Comment: Still the same answer : per definition, a *unit test* tests an *unit* : if you test that your service does something, you're testnig *two units*.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean properly now. This unit is just to call the authService.logout, the test I am trying to incorporate into the one you showed should be used within the authService.spec to test the logout function itself! Thanks :-)

Also... I'd been looking for how to spy on things like this! Lifesaver

Comment: Exactly ! and no problem, consider [reading the doc](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.0/global) to find everything you can do with Jasmine !